# how to draw scatter with zeppelin that contains 3 types of points

Tags: matplotlib, apache-zeppelin

I'm working with zeppelin notebook using spark interpreter, I want to get a scatter but I want to get these points to have 3 different colors.

I integrated matplotlib in zeppelin because is simple to plot different pandas dataframe in the same figure.

```
      import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

      # get object from ResourcePool

      MemArb=sqlContext.table("MemArb")
      VoisArb=sqlContext.table("VoisArb")
      SousTest=sqlContext.table("SousTest")

      MemArb=MemArb.toPandas()
      VoisArb=VoisArb.toPandas()
      SousTest=SousTest.toPandas()

      x_client = SousTest["derx"].
      astype('float').iloc[0]
      y_client = SousTest["dtrx"].
      astype('float').iloc[0]

      x_memeArbre = MemArb['valx'].astype('float')
      y_memeArbre = MemArb['valOx'].astype('float')
      x_voisinArbre = VoisArb['vax'].astype('float')
      y_voisinArbre = VoisArb['valOx'].astype('float')

      y_voisinArbre.count()
      figure(num=None, figsize=(10, 8), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
      plt.scatter(x_client, y_client, s=90, color='b')
      plt.scatter(x_memeArbre,y_memeArbre,s=10, color='r')
      plt.scatter(x_voisinArbre, y_voisinArbre, s=10, color='b')
      plt.title('Nuage de points avec Matplotlib')
      plt.xlabel('ONx')
      plt.ylabel('OLx')
      plt.show()
```

Is there a solution to get the same result using Zeppelin without matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

You can use `createOrReplaceTempView` function on a dataframe and then write SQL queries to get the data. Current Zeppelin (0.8.0) has a scatter plot among offered built-in visualizations. Just make sure that each data point has a corresponding column indicating color.